# Grouping switch statement cases together?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I may be over looking something but is there a simple way in C++ to group cases together instead of writing them out individually? I remember in basic I could just do:

```
SELECT CASE Answer
CASE 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Example in C++ (For those that need it):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int Answer;
   cout << "How many cars do you have?";
   cin >> Answer;
   switch (Answer)                                      
      {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
         cout << "You need more cars. ";
         break;                                        
      case 5:
      case 6:
      case 7:
      case 8:
         cout << "Now you need a house. ";
         break;                                        
      default:
         cout << "What are you? A peace-loving hippie freak? ";
      }
      cout << "\nPress ENTER to continue... " << endl;
      getchar();
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Umm, I think you answered your own question...

Comment: For the particular example you've provided an easier way would be `if (Answer >=1 && Answer <=4)`

Comment: @Falmari No, he wants an even more compact form such as `case 1, 2, 3, 4:`

Comment: I realize I'm doing it correctly. I'm just using my resources to find the best way to do things. As redundant as C++ is, I would of expected a better way of grouping outputs then typing case 400 times just to group outputs.

Comment: GCC will now report `Wimplicit-fallthrough` if you perform `case 1: case 2:` etc, so it would be nice to have an elegant cross-platform way of handling this without having to disable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but you can with an `if`-`else if`-`else` chain which achieves the same result:

```
if (answer >= 1 && answer <= 4)
  cout << "You need more cars.";
else if (answer <= 8)
  cout << "Now you need a house.";
else
  cout << "What are you? A peace-loving hippie freak?";
```

You may also want to handle the case of 0 cars and then also the unexpected case of a negative number of cars probably by throwing an exception.

PS: I've renamed `Answer` to `answer` as it's considered bad style to start variables with an uppercase letter.

As a side note, scripting languages such as Python allow for the nice `if answer in [1, 2, 3, 4]` syntax which is a flexible way of achieving what you want.

Comment: It sucks that relational operators cant be used in a switch statement... :-\

Comment: @Josh What's got you so attached to switch statements though? If they don't provide what you need, use a more suitable alternative.

Comment: Nothing really. I was just reading an article on Branching Statements and noticed they put a lot of time on them and I for some reason I thought there was another way to group them. I've honestly only used Switch Statements when I first started programming.

Answer (score 47):

AFAIK all you can do is omit the returns to make things more compact in C++:

```
switch(Answer)
{
    case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
        cout << "You need more cars.";
        break;
    ...
}
```

(You could remove the other returns as well, of course.)

Comment: You need spaces between `case` and the number don't you?

Comment: @marcog, Yes! Fixed it, ta for noticing.

Answer (score 22):

Sure you can.

You can use case x ... y for the range

Example:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int Answer;
   cout << "How many cars do you have?";
   cin >> Answer;
   switch (Answer)                                      
      {
      case 1 ... 4:
         cout << "You need more cars. ";
         break;                                        
      case 5 ... 8:
         cout << "Now you need a house. ";
         break;                                        
      default:
         cout << "What are you? A peace-loving hippie freak? ";
      }
      cout << "\nPress ENTER to continue... " << endl;
      getchar();
      return 0;
}
```

Make sure you have "-std=c++0x" flag enabled within your compiler

Comment: Note that this is a GNU extension, not standard c++ 11.

Answer (score 6):

You can use like this:

```
case 4: case 2:
 {
   //code ...
 }
```

For use 4 or 2 switch case.

Answer (score 5):

Your example is as concise as it gets with the `switch` construct.

Comment: Wrong. As said on other answers, he could write more than one `case` on the same line for grouping them together, or even using ranges with `...`. Please, edit or remove your answer.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Whitespace doesn't count, and the range feature is not standard C++. The other answers with different approaches are visible to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove keyword `case`. But  your example can be written shorter like this:

```
switch ((Answer - 1) / 4)                                      
{
   case 0:
      cout << "You need more cars.";
      break;                                        
   case 1:
      cout << "Now you need a house.";
      break;                                        
   default:
      cout << "What are you? A peace-loving hippie freak?";
}
```

Comment: I like this idea actually. Thanks!

Comment: It really is the only way to still use the switch statement and not have to define each case.

Comment: This code is trying to be smart. Generally that is not a good thing. But it is the answer :-). Just beware, shorter is not always better.

Comment: if we are going down this road, how about #define CASE1234 case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to go the way of the preprocessor abuse, [`Boost.Preprocessor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) can help you.

```
    #include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

    #define CASE_case(ign, ign2, n) case n:

    #define CASES(seq) \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(CASE_case, ~, seq)

    CASES((1)(3)(15)(13))
```

Running this through `gcc` with `-E -P` to only run the preprocessor, the expansion of `CASES` gives:

```
    case 1: case 3: case 15: case 13:
```

Note that this probably wouldn't pass a code review (wouldn't where I work!) so I recommend it be constrained to personal use.

It should also be possible to create a `CASE_RANGE(1,5)` macro to expand to

```
    case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
```

for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

gcc has a so-called "case range" extension:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges

I used to use this when I was only using gcc. Not much to say about it really -- it does sort of what you want, though only for ranges of values.

The biggest problem with this is that only gcc supports it; this may or may not be a problem for you.

(I suspect that for your example an `if` statement would be a more natural fit.)

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you want to break compatibility *and* your compiler supports it.

Comment: Wrong. As said on other answers, he could write more than one `case` on the same line for grouping them together, or even using ranges with `...`. Please, edit or remove your answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n = 2;
int main()
{
     switch(n)
     {
          case 0: goto _4;break;
          case 1: goto _4;break;
          case 2: goto _4;break;
          case 3: goto _4;break;
          case 4:
              _4:
                printf("Funny and easy!\n");
                break;
          default:
                printf("Search on StackOverflow!\n");
                break;
     }
}
```

Comment: This does not helps at all, and makes the code fugly. As said on other answers, he could write more than one `case` on the same line for grouping them together, or even using ranges with `...`. Please, edit or remove your answer.