# How do I test a list against a variable inputted using the cin function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to mess around with the switch function and I want to use cin to allow me to input a number, then test it using a list of prime and not prime to see if the number is prime or not

here is the code I was working with.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int prime[]{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, };
    int composite[]{ 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, };
    int x;
    
    cout << "Pick A Number Between 1-19: ";
    cin >> x;

    switch (x) {
    case : // I don't know how to make this case search the prime list
        
            
        cout << "its prime" << endl;
        break;
    case :    // I don't know how to make this case search the composite list
        
        cout << "Its Composite" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "default case" << endl;


        return 0;
}
```

My Problem:  I have the list of prime and composite number but I don't know how to make the switch statement test against them.

Comment: @drescherjm if input fails the integer will get `0` assigned. One of the most frequently missed c++11 features

Comment: Now for your problem. I am not sure where you would use a swich for this.

Comment: Stop messing around. It's slow and not very fault tolerant. What you should do is come up with a plan.

Comment: @idclev 463035818  Thank you for the correction, I miss it because I develop `Qt` GUI applications nearly 100% of the time with the rare occasion to use `cin`

Comment: please show your code. From your description it is not clear what exactly you want to do. Questions about problems with code should include a [mcve] and the compiler error (or describe expected behavior)

Comment: well, you just have to add that part: "test it using a list of prime and not prime to see if the number is prime or not" then the code does what you want. It is possible. What your specific question is is unclear. Please take the [tour] and read [How-to-ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your code itself does not really test for prime. However the question of using a variable initialized from a cin in a switch  you have successfully done that.

Comment: ***I want to use a list to hold the prime and composite numbers but i don't know how to access them while doing this.*** `std::vector<int> prime, composite;` before your input then `prime.push_back(x);` or `composite.push_back(x);` in your case. You will need a loop if you expect the user to enter more than 1 number.

Comment: `switch` tests a single (primitive) value against separate (primitive) values, all of which must be known at compile time.

Comment: Also I believe 1 is not prime and 2 is not composite.

Comment: I say the whole switch / case is the wrong approach. Create a `bool isPrime(int number)` function. Have it return true if the number is prime. You don't even have to write this function on your own. If you search there should be thousands of questions containing code for this function.

Comment: If you really want a switch()  / case. You will have to manually add every prime number as a case. Use 1. for a different case and default: for the composite.

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of `switch/case`. Just use `if (is_prime(x)) { ... } else { ... }`. There's no third possibility.

Comment: 1 is not prime or composite but that is for a different discussion.

Comment: so I should Not use switch for this "project" if I want to use the list good to know. can i ask a side question here: can i add more than one number to each case and if so how

Comment: You could use a list if the rules of the homework allow it. Most homework would require that you find the prime numbers in a loop instead of a table lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the [switch statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) then you shall do it this way:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    
    cout << "Pick a number between 1-19: ";
    cin >> x;

    switch (x) {
    case 2: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 11: case 13: case 17: case 19:
        cout << "it's prime" << endl;
        break;
    case 4: case 6: case 8: case 9: case 10: case 12: case 14: case 15: case 16: case 18:
        cout << "it's composite" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "default case" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please have a look to this SO post for more information about

[Grouping switch statement cases together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494170/grouping-switch-statement-cases-together)

Hope it helps?